# reducer function error when using redux-toolkit

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I got the following error when I was using redux:

```
TypeError: react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2___default(...) is not a function
```

How do I solve this? I have added the code below.

`dispatch()` is being called in the component below

```
import authAction from "../store/Auth";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
  },
  menuButton: {
    marginRight: theme.spacing(2),
  },
  title: {
    flexGrow: 1,
  },
}));

export default function Header() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  console.log("Auth:", authAction);

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <AppBar position="static">
        <Toolbar>
          <Typography variant="h6" className={classes.title}>
            Counter
          </Typography>
          <Button
            color="inherit"
            onClick={() => {
              dispatch(authAction.login());
            }}
          >
            Login
          </Button>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
    </div>
  );
}
```

`creatSlice` component:

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const authSlice = createSlice({
  name: "Auth",
  initialState: { loggedIn: false },
  reducers: {
    login(state) {
      state.loggedIn = true;
    },
  },
});

export const authActions = authSlice.actions;

export default authSlice.reducer;
```

`configureStore` component:

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import auth from "./Auth";

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    auth: auth,
  },
});

export default store;
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Issue

Your auth actions aren't the default export from your slice:

```
export const authActions = authSlice.actions;

export default authSlice.reducer;
```

but you are importing them as if they were:

```
import authAction from "../store/Auth";
```

## Solution

Correctly import the named `authActions` export:

```
import { authActions } from "../store/Auth";
```

and dispatch the correct action creator:

```
<Button
  color="inherit"
  onClick={() => {
    dispatch(authActions.login());
  }}
>
  Login
</Button>
```